# unhandled exception error won't allow me to insert data

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

So if i run this code i'm thrown a multi-part identifier errorregarding the binding of the textbox "clid"

Can somebody please help to resolve this issue?

```
Using cnnentry As New SqlConnection("Data Source=NB-1492\sqlipt;Initial Catalog=Bookings;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
    Dim entrclientid As String
    Dim clid As New TextBox
    clid = FormView1.FindControl("txtclientid")
    entrclientid = Convert.ToString(clid)
    Dim sqlentry1 As String = "INSERT INTO BOOKING_DETAILS(CLIENT_ID) VALUES("
    Dim sqlentry2 As String = entrclientid
    Dim sqlentry3 As String = ")"
    Dim sqlentry4 As String = sqlentry1 & sqlentry2 & sqlentry3
    Dim cmdclientid As New SqlCommand(sqlentry4, cnnentry)
    cnnentry.Open()
    string1 = cmdclientid.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnnentry.Close()
End Using
```

Thanks in advance

P.S. please excuse the naming conventions i wrote this extremely quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to convert the `TextBox` to a `String` but it's `Text` property:

change

```
entrclientid = Convert.ToString(clid)
```

to

```
entrclientid = clid.Text
```

But more important, you should use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection.

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO BOOKING_DETAILS(CLIENT_ID) VALUES(@CLIENT_ID)"
Dim cmdclientid As New SqlCommand(sql, cnnentry)
cmdclientid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CLIENT_ID", clid.Text)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for that... it actually works now... i've been trying for three days to do this in various ways :D